# Python Pandas Result of dataframe groupby agg to dict to be easily used outside of pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe that I'm grouping as seen below:
`df_sums = df.groupby(["Product", "Year", "Month"]).agg({"Quantity": "sum"})`

When I check the result in the console, it prints this data exactly as I want, with clear division / grouping, example below:

```
Product          Year Month             Quantity
product1         2022 01                10092
                      02                30902
                      03                23475
                      04                10082
                      05                 7148
                 2023 01                12238
                      02                 7148
product2         2022 01                16830
                      02                17791
                      03                20040
                      04                12979
```

I want this result in a form of dictionary, or anything other that would be simple to use outside of pandas, as for example I would like to extract from it every quantity for a specific month in a specific year for a specific part etc. but I can't find any solution for that.

So far I used: .to_dict() with every possible parameter, I tried transposing, working with indexes, trying to make it a list and some other solutions for a similar questions but I do not know how to tackle this.

A basic result of simple .to_dict() gives me what is below but I can't access this easily, even with a use of .items() as I can't iterate through it normally as .items() gives me even less:

```
{'Quantity': {('product1', '2022', '01'): 10092,
                    ('product1', '2022', '02'): 30902,
                    ('product1', '2022', '03'): 23475,
                    ('product1', '2022', '04'): 10082,
                    ('product1', '2022', '05'): 7148,
                    ('product1', '2023', '01'): 12238,
                    ('product1', '2023', '02'): 7148,
                    ('product2', '2022', '01'): 16830,
                    ('product2', '2022', '02'): 17791,
                    ('product2', '2022', '03'): 20040,
                    ('product2', '2022', '04'): 12979,}}
```

Comment: why `df_sums.to_dict()['Quantity']` would not work? It gives you result for "for a specific month in a specific year for a specific part etc"

Answer (score 1):

When you're using the `.to_dict()` function on a Pandas dataframe with multiple columns, the key will be a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuples) of the values of all the other columns, with the last column being the value of the key. That dictionary is nestled in another one with the column itself.

So the original output is in the format of:

```
>>> dict_output = your_dataframe.to_dict()
>>> dict_output

{'Quantity': { #Dictonary of your data }

>>> dict_output['Quantity']

{('Product','Year','Month'): Quantity}
```

So if you wanted to access the data for product 1 in march of 2022, it would look like this:

```
>>> dict_output = your_dataframe.to_dict()
>>> dict_output = dict_output['Quantity']
>>> dict_output[('product1','2022','03')]
23475
```

My tuple would be ('Product','Year','Month') to get the output of 'Quantity'.

Hope that helps!